# Is it ok to use a frame hardboard siding as a tennis wall?

Tags: siding

The exterior of my house is made of frame hardboard. My wife says that I should not use it as a tennis wall because tennis size hail are known to damage the siding and therefore a tennis ball would damage it too if I hit the wall with the ball too many times. I say the material/object properties of ice and a hollow rubber ball are very different, particularly the coefficient of restitution. But I don't have any hard evidence that bouncing the tennis ball off the siding over many months won't do any damage to the siding. Any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hitting a tennis ball hard against "hardboard" siding would be expected at the very least to damage the paint and perhaps breakdown the siding over time.

Comment: I don’t think the siding would last long at all. I like hardboard siding but it is very brittle the flex will not be good as the fasteners will quickly start to abrade the hard board material.

Answer (score 0):

Hardie Panel is designed to deal with hail - tennis balls would cause much less impact.  Yeah, it might damage paint and yeah it might accelerate replacement but the alternative is putting a different board in front of it. That’s not cheap either.  So I’m planning to use a Hardie Panel wall as a tennis wall and will report back on paint and other impact after a season of use.

Comment: "hardboard" is not necessarily Hardie Panel, so this may or may not be of use to the OP. Also, if you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum and you haven't really provided an answer, more of a comment. In a year, providing your result as an answer would be quite helpful, as of now, it's not so helpful in our format.